# Angular ng-select load async data when (open) event is fired

Tags: angular, select, autocomplete, rxjs, dropdown

I'm using [ng-select](https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/search) custom server-side search to load data based on what the user types. Currently it only works if a keyword is actually pressed.

```angular
<ng-select [items]="filterValues$ | async"
    [typeahead]="filterValuesInput$"
    [multiple]="true"
    (open)="getFilterValues(pref.id)"
    [loading]="filterValuesLoading"
    bindLabel="name"
    [(ngModel)]="filter_values">
</ng-select>
```

I want to trigger the API request when the select dropdown opens, **even** if no search term is provided.

```typescript
getFilterValues(filterId) {
    this.filterValues$ = concat(
      of([]), // default items
      this.filterValuesInput$.pipe(
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        tap(() => this.filterValuesLoading = true),
        switchMap(term => this.service.getFilterValues(filterName, '' + term).pipe(
          map(res => res.filter_values),
          catchError(() => of([])), // empty list on error
          tap(() => this.filterValuesLoading = false)
        ))
      )
    );
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because the concat is not emitting any value cause of the second observable. You can try using startWith operator for the initial loading

```
getFilterValues(filterId) {
    this.filterValues$ = concat(
      of([]), // default items
      this.filterValuesInput$.pipe(
        startWith(''),
        debounce(300),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        tap(() => this.filterValuesLoading = true),
        switchMap(term => this.service.getFilterValues(filterName, '' + term).pipe(
          map(res => res.filter_values),
          catchError(() => of([])), // empty list on error
          tap(() => this.filterValuesLoading = false)
        ))
      )
    );
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This answear must be marked as answer, it really works